# Ubuntu 14.04lts, USB Keyboard and USB mouse Just stop working

Tags: 14.04, usb, keyboard, mouse

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04LTS since Sept 2015 without any problems.  Within the last week or so the USB keyboard and mouse just stops working.  The only way to cure the problem is to do a hard reboot.  I have been reading the forum and trying suggested fixes, so far nothing has worked.  There was an update last Tuesday, 5 Apr 2016 and that is was around that time the problem started.  Initially, It was one program, when I started it, it would hang as soon as I selected an item in the program (and still does).  Then I noticed it would hang once in a while at other times.  So, I kind of think it isn't a single program but maybe the latest up date.  I did have a problem running the software updater, I had to run it from the terminal.  Does anyone have an idea what is causing this?

4/09/16 This morning I got the following error "Sorry Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error".  The error is as follows:

Package
     linux-image-3.16.0-69-9generic 3.16.0-69-89~14.04.1
Problem Type
     KernelOops
Title
     BUG: Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000008
Annotation
     Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted
Date
     Sat Apr 9 08:53:20 2016
Dependencies

Failure
     Oops
Installation Date
     Installed on 2015-08-04 (294 days ago)
Installation Media
     Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS "Trusty Tahr" Release (20150218.1)
Oops Text
     BUG: Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000008
     IP [] radeon_fence_ref+0xd/0x50[radeon]
     PGDO
     Oops:002[#1]SMP
     CPU: 1PID: 1633 Comm: Xorg Not Tainted 3.16.0-69-9generic #89~14.04.1   ubuntu
     Hardware Name: System manufactured System product name M4A785-M (ASUS)
     Bios 1006 08/18/2010

There is more but I can't save the error report or even copy parts of it.  If you need more data or different data please let me know. I tried to format this like the report but I don't think it will post like that.  Any help in what I posted?  Thanks for your assistance in figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  I don't know the technical reason why it is fixed.  The program that I first noticed the problem had a extension add-on that collected data from google.  I didn't use the add-on any longer but didn't see any reason to remove it.  For what ever reason, the add-on was causing the problem or else, the software update for 14.04 I received yesterday fixed the problem.  Anyway, it's fixed.  Thanks one and all for at least looking at my problem.